# Is there any way we can install .NETFramework 4.7.1 nuget into project using .netstandard2.0 or .netstandard3.0

Tags: c#, .net, .net-standard

I am trying to install nuget which was built using .NET Framework 4.7.1 into project which is on .netstandard 2.0. However, I am getting warning like

> Package 'xyz' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1' instead of the project target framework '.netstandard2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

and nuget package is not getting installed correctly causing file missing exceptions when I run unit test cases. I can see 2 options resolving this issue :

1. I should change my original nuget package to support .NET Framework 4.7.1 as well .netstandard 2.0. Not sure if this is feasible? If yes please let me know the steps.
2. Changes my nuget consumer project to use both of these versions.
   I have given couple of tries to figure out the way using above options but still not luck!

Comment: I'm finding your question very hard to understand, particularly as you don't actually show the warning. It would really help if you'd provide a [mcve] - the two projects, with the reference between them. There doesn't need to be any source code as such - just the project files, and what currently happens.

Comment: @JonSkeet I added the warning

Comment: But you didn't clarify the question in any other way. It's still one big chunk of text, which is really hard to understand.

Comment: It would also help if you'd give details of the exact exceptions you're running into - and ideally include the code that provokes this. At the moment we can't really tell whether the library *might* be compatible with .NET Standard with a bit of work, or whether the very little hope of getting it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your response! I was able to figure out the solution by creating new .net standard project and migrating the .net framework code to it.
Good Reference to brush up the basics about these .NET offerings : https://code-maze.com/differences-between-net-framework-net-core-and-net-standard/